# Improve a fitted Ellipse using EmguCV (2.4) in C#

Tags: c#, ellipse, emgucv

I'm using EmguCV 2.4 in C# for edge detection and ellipse fitting of ellipsoid objects in a picture (e.g. laser spot).

EmguCV has implemented functions for fitting an ellipse to a point cloud using the least squares method, but the ellipses do not fit very well to the ellipsoids, depending on their angle.

Here's a basic code, I'm using:

```
CHAIN_APPROX_METHOD approxMethod = CHAIN_APPROX_METHOD.CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE;
RETR_TYPE           RetrType     = RETR_TYPE.CV_RETR_LIST;

Bitmap Bmp = new Bitmap(@"C:\Users\pernizki\Downloads\binary2.bmp");                // read Bitmap
Image<Bgr,  byte> ImgIn   = new Image<Bgr, byte>(Bmp);                              // Convert to Image<>
Image<Gray, byte> ImgBin  = ImgIn.Convert<Gray, byte>();                            // convert Bgr to Gray
ImgBin = ImgBin.ThresholdBinary(new Gray(140), new Gray(120)).PyrDown().PyrUp();    // convert to binary and reduce noise
ImgBin = ImgBin.Canny(100, 120);                                                    // detect the edges from binary image
Contour<Point>    Contour = ImgBin.FindContours(approxMethod, RetrType);            // Get Contour from binary Image
int cntr = 0;
PointF[] ContourPts = new PointF[Contour.Total];

// Convert Contour to PointF Array
foreach(Point p in Contour)
{
    ContourPts[cntr++] = new PointF(p.X, p.Y);
}

Ellipse fittedEllipse = PointCollection.EllipseLeastSquareFitting(ContourPts);

ImgIn.Draw(Contour, new Bgr(Color.Green), 2);
ImgIn.Draw(fittedEllipse, new Bgr(Color.Tomato), 2);

CvInvoke.cvShowImage("Fitted Ellipse", ImgIn.Ptr);
```

When I have vertical or horizontal ellipse as an input image, the fitted ellipse is always 90° rotated to the input shape. If the angle is something between 0° and 90° the fitted ellipse is still rotated, but at different angle.

I understand, that this problem is fundamental to the least square method. But are there more robust algorithms to fit an ellipse, that is enclosing all of the points? 
The picture in the [EmguCV tutorial](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Ellipse_Fitting_in_CSharp) for fitting an ellipse seems to be exactly, what I'm looking for. Unfortunately, that's not how the function works.

Here's an example image, that I've used. 
(sorry for having only one, as I don't have enough reputation for more)

[rotated Ellipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/msYh9.png)

Comment: Here's the output image, that I get with the code from above. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3a8Q1.png

Comment: I am facing same issue.